# Angular Component Unit Testing - Component within Components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have a question regarding creating unit tests in Angular 2 (Final release -  2.0.0). How can I test a component that depends on other components.

For example, the **app.component.ts**, my **app.component.ts** depends on other components like **HomeComponent** and other components. In the app.component.ts, this is not a problem since the modules are imported in via **app.module.ts**.

However, in the **app.component.spec.ts**, I do not know how to structure this as it would not accept a Module as an import. Also, when I run the test, the **app.component.spec.ts** asks for the declaration of third party libraries, but I cannot import the module of the third party library, and I cannot import the components inside the module one by one.

I am using the latest angular-cli by the way that uses webpack already. Do I need to configure something in order for me to perform tests?

The Angular testing website guide ([Angular 2 - Testing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html)) does not show how to do this. I would really appreciate the help as I am stuck with this issue.

Here is the code:

```
describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports:[
        AppModuleComponents
      ]
    });
  });
```

I am prompted with this error after running ng test:
[Error image after running ng test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEOei.png)

Comment: mmm... hard to tell what you are asking without code, you should be able to include the modules using something like: `fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpModule, DhcpModule],
            providers: [
                {provide: TranslationService, useValue: translationService},
                {provide: SessionsService, useValue: sessionsService},
                {provide: DhcpConfigService, useValue: dhcpConfigService},
            ]
        }).createComponent(DhcpPoolComponent);`

Comment: Post the code you are currently using to try to setup the modules for the test

Comment: Ok. I will edit the post to include the code and the screenshot.

Comment: I don't know why it asks for the HomeComponent  when I didn't call it from **app.component.ts**. However, it is just routed by the **app.component.ts**.

Comment: You do have to declare all the modules that are used by subcomponents, just like you do in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Does this mean I have to declare them one by one?

Comment: It feels off that you also have to declare the modules used by the sub-components. This seems to violate unit testing concept. Instead, it is preferable to create mocks of the sub-components